# How can I set text in Fragment between Adapter?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can set text in `Fragment` between `Adapter`?

Explain:

`Fragment` use  `explor.xml`  layout
`Adapter` use `store_list.xml` layout

Because I had used `LocationListener` in `Fragment`, so when I got the latitude and longitude, as same time I still got lat and lng from firebase DB.

```
double radLat1 = rad(camperSiteModel1.getCamperSiteLatitude());
double radLat2 = rad(latitude);
double a = radLat1 - radLat2;
double b = rad(camperSiteModel1.getCamperSiteLongitude()) - rad(longitude);
double s = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin(a / 2), 2)
           + Math.cos(radLat1) * Math.cos(radLat2)
           * Math.pow(Math.sin(b / 2), 2)));
s = s * EARTH_RADIUS * 1.609344;
s = Math.round(s * 10000) / 10000;
Log.i("distance",s+"");
distance.setText(s);
```

I set `distance = view.findViewById(R.id.distance);` in `Fragment` and set `distance.setText(s);`

fragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container,false);
distance = view.findViewById(R.id.distance);

readDate();
}

private void readCampSite(){
 //Firebase code ...
    distance.setText(s);
}
```

Should I set TextView distance in adapter?
Adapter.java

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   distance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
}
```

And final, how can setText in distance in fragment list.xml?

I got this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null
> object reference

Where has problem?

Comment: Did you apply distance.setText(s); after inflate your layout ? public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.explor, container, false);
            distance = view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            distance.setText(s);
            return view;
        }

Comment: @ZahidIslam yes, I've apply distance = view.findViewById(R.id.distance); in fragment  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater....), but I dont know why has problem

Comment: is your distance textview in store_list.xml?